# Rails: search form in boostrap navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add search form to bootstrap navbar with no luck. Search form works fine in app/views/searches/new.html.erb. When I add the same search form in app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb, I get 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty' all the time. I tried to change @search in form to search paths, but none of them works properly. 
I'd appreciate any tips how to make the code better, I feel like I could've written the code in search model in more elegant way. 
Thank you for help.

app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @search, html: {class: "navbar-form navbar-left"} do |f| %>
 <div class="input-group searchbar">
 <%= f.text_field :keywords, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   <%= button_tag(:class => "white") do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
   <% end %>
   </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

search model

```
def questions
 @questions = find_questions
end

def answers
 @answers =  find_answers
end

def users
 @users = find_users
end

private

def find_questions
 questions = Question.order(created_at: :desc)
 questions = questions.where("title like ? OR content like?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
 questions
end

def find_answers
 answers = Answer.order(created_at: :desc)
 answers = answers.where("content like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
 answers
end

def find_users
 users = User.order(:username)
 users = users.where("username like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
 users
end
```

searches controller

```
def new
 @search = Search.new
end

def create
 @search = Search.create!(allowed_params)
 redirect_to @search
end

def show
 @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end

private

def allowed_params
 params.require(:search).permit!
end
```

questions controller - I have the same code in answers and users controllers

```
def index
 @questions = Question.all
 if params[:search]
  @questions = Question.search(params[:search])
 end
end
```

routes

```
searches GET      /searches(.:format)                       searches#index
         POST     /searches(.:format)                       searches#create
new_search GET    /searches/new(.:format)                   searches#new
edit_search GET   /searches/:id/edit(.:format)              searches#edit
search GET      /searches/:id(.:format)                   searches#show
       PATCH    /searches/:id(.:format)                   searches#update
       PUT      /searches/:id(.:format)                   searches#update
       DELETE   /searches/:id(.:format)                   searches#destroy
root GET      /                                         home#index
```

Comment: when u get that error, after clicking or before ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I get it when I try to open my website, I mean the first thing I see when I open localhost is that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested, but it should work. Don't forget to change `search_path` to your own one.

```
<%= form_tag ###search_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'keywords', nil, placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!